# Unix: File copying using creat() open() and check file type in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, file-io, copy

I am currently making program in C and linux. This program allows me to copy file from current directory **to another directory** or copy the file and paste it in **current directory**

E.g.: My program is call **copy** and i have a folder name **Folder** and file name **FILE**

If i type:      **./copy FILE FILE2**. A new file name FILE2 will be create in current directory.

If I type:      **./copy FILE Folder** A new file name **FILE** will be create in **Folder** directory

**Is there a way to check the second argument to see if it's a FILE name or a directory** because i want the program to determine which function to run when  the argument is received.

Can this be done without using any other function. (Which is only using creat() and open() function)

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: That behavior is already built-in to most shells, why do you need a separate program?

Comment: well, using cp can be easy, but making one can be challenging and in some case, these function needs to be rebuilt or built.